# Get ID of last element and save to shortcode

Tags: jquery, shortcode

I have a bunch of buttons on my page:

```
<a href="#" role="button" id="start">
<a href="#" role="button" id="go">
<a href="#" role="button" id="back">
```

Is there a way to get the ID of the last button clicked and save it to a shortcode? Ideally I just want to add [lastbutton] to my page and it will display "start", "go", or "back", depending on which one was clicked last.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at below code. convert links into button and for demo element, you can choose any type of element like button,

or

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="start";
  })
  $("#go").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="go";
  })
  $("#back").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="back";
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" role="button" id="start">start</a>
<a href="#" role="button" id="go">go</a>
<a href="#" role="button" id="back">back</a>

<p id="demo">lb</p>
```